# ngModel binding with input ranges

Tags: angularjs

I have this case where there are two inputs that I want to bind on the same object , they represent start and end of a range

```
<input type="number" ng-model="price.values[0]"> - <input type ="number" ng-model="price.values[1]">
```

the issue is that when I enter one value and leave the other empty this is what I get inside the object :

> values :
>
> 0: 111
>
> 1: NaN

I am wondering about the NaN part what exactly is going on and how can I avoid binding to NaN when its empty

Comment: What would you like to get instead of NaN, when value is empty?

Comment: just to keep it empty @Kasyx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply preset values to `null` or `undefined` in your controller:

```
$scope.price = {
    values: [ null, null ]
}
```

Here you have working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gf5excbt/